# Slick Slider no link and lightbox on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

I have a Slick Slider working (within TYPO3 CMS MASK) which is working great on large screen. But on mobile the applied link or light-box, swipe is not working? Could the surrounding `<div class="test_">` causing this behaviour? Other images not in the slider, with lightbox are working fine.

This is the slick js applied. The lightbox = fancy-box.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sh_product_slider2').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    dots: true,
    centerMode: false,
    variableWidth: true,
    infinite: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    touchMove: false,
    prevArrow:'<button class="slick-prev"> < </button>',
    nextArrow:'<button class="slick-next"> > </button>',
      responsive: [                        
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
          centerMode: false,
          variableWidth: true,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 2500,
          swipeToSlide: true,
          pauseOnHover: true, 
          pauseOnFocus: true,
          arrows:false,
          touchMove: true,
          focusOnSelect: true
         }
       },
     ]
   });
});
```

This is the generated html:

[image]

Made a codepen to see what's wrong but same behaviour as on the site applied.  Any thoughts on this?
Codepen:

https://codepen.io/mr_vespa/pen/qBNgzWm

Comment: Any thoughts on this? Do not see why it is not working on mobile. Saw different codepen which where working also on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: removing  z-index: 2; from

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { 
.sh_product_slider2 {
    position: relative;
    /*z-index: 2; */
    padding: 0 0px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    max-width: 1155px;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

made it work.